# Replacing similar terms with one word in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I apologize in advance, because I'm not entirely sure how to word this question.

I'm maintaining financial records for a student organization, and my goal is to make a spreadsheet that is easy to use, so a solid, up-to-date format can be passed down across many years.

There are several positions within the organization, and they each have budgets for certain things.

Right now, I have a ledger set up that is set up like the following:

Budget ----- Sub-budget ---- Description of trans. ---- Amount
President -- Leadership ----- Plane tickets -------------- $

With the drop-down list, users can either enter text, or pick from the list. (I'm using the Data Validation option, with 'list' selected.) I don't want to restrict non-list data, because I want the sheet to be easy to use. On the other hand, I don't want free reign with naming, because the titles are fairly long, and I want to be able to account for everything automatically.

So I thought good middle ground would be to replace similar data to the data I want.

So, for instance, a user might type under Budget:

- President
- Pres
- P
- pRez

I can recognize that all of these are referring to 'President', and so I want the input to be replaced with 'President'.

I know that I could add a hidden column that interprets these using a basic formula, but I'd like to add something that does this replacement automatically; as soon as the user hits 'Enter', I'd like the spreadsheet to automatically change this to an approved term.

At the same time, I would like any other term not covered to be given a default change value; any other value that's not a term for President or any other position, classify it as 'Other'.

Is this possible to do? Would this require VBA, or is this functionality built in under existing settings?

Comment: You would certainly need vba. My suggestion would be to go with the helper column, as it's significantly easier.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the user to input data in a particular cell and, once they have finished, you want that same cell to be changed to meet some sanitized list of allowable terms.

The only way that I know of to change the data in a cell is through VBA. Your options are to either use a hidden field like you mention or to use VBA. Either way, you're going to need a table showing all the unofficial terms and what the corresponding official term is.

The rest of the approach relies on which is more important: Ease of implementation or appearance of the finished product. For instance, if it's really important that you can print and have the official terms show up or if you want to make sure that your users see exactly what they typed in showing up in other places, then the helper column may not work out and you'll have to go with VBA.

If you're OK with that, let us know and we can put together an example of how to get this to work.

---

**EDIT: OP is OK with VBA solution**
First, here is the setup:

- I have a hidden worksheet called `WordTable` whose codename (in VBA) is `shtWordTable`
- In that hidden sheet is a table (or list, if you're old school) whose name is `tblWordTable`
- That table has two fields: `Nickname` and `Proper Name`
- `Nickname` has values like Pres, P, pRez (god help that user)
- `Proper Name` has values like President, President, and President
- I have a visible worksheet called `Ledger` whose codename is `shtLedger`
- That worksheet has a table called `tblLedger`
- That table has the 4 fields you mention in your question

Note that the solution will work if your data isn't in an official table and is just a block of cells but I like tables and they're useful for lots of things so I'm using that in the example. I'll comment the code so you can tell which lines to edit.
With that setup, go into VBA and can create a `Worksheet_Change` event within `shtLedger`. That will trigger every time data changes in any cell in that worksheet. We'll make it check to see if it's within the range we want to auto-correct and, if it is, look for a replacement in the `WordTable`. If one is found, we'll swap it out.

The code is probably longer than it needs to be for your exact situation but, since I don't know what *your* setup looks like, I've tried to just make it as robust as possible. There are also some comments sections just to help. Your final result should be a little shorter than this:

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Declarations
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rngAutocorrect As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    'Setup what cells we want to check for nicknames
    'It will error if the table has no data in it because DataBodyRange will be nothing
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rngAutocorrect = ListObjects("tblLedger").ListColumns("Budget").DataBodyRange
    On Error GoTo 0

    'If it did error out so there is no data in the table so we exit
    If rngAutocorrect Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'If you're not using a table, you can do something like this:
    ' Set rngAutocorrect = Range("A:A")
    'The only important thing is that you end up with a range object

    'If there are multiple areas to check, one method is to use Union to add them
    'You can also define them all at once, but the Union method trades longer code for easier debugging
    ' Set rngAutocorrect = Union(rngAutocorrect, ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Sub-Budget").DataBodyRange)
    ' Set rngAutocorrect = Union(rngAutocorrect, Range("B:B"))

    'Check if what was changed (Target) is within the range we want to Autocorrect
    If Not Intersect(Target, rngAutocorrect) Is Nothing Then
        'Store the lookup table in an easy-to-reference format
        Set tbl = shtWordTable.ListObjects("tblWordTable")

        'Target might be a range of cells if, for instance, they have pasted a lot of text in
        'Loop through each in turn
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            'Check that this particular cell needs autocorrecting
            If Not Intersect(Target, rngAutocorrect) Is Nothing Then
                'Look for the value in the word table
                With shtWordTable.ListObjects(1)
                    'Change the parameters here if you want to match case or something
                    Set rngFound = .ListColumns("Nickname").DataBodyRange.Find( _
                        cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
                    'If we found it, then grab the Proper Name
                    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                        'Turn off events or else this code will trigger itself in an infinite loop
                        Application.EnableEvents = False

                        'Make the switch
                        cell.Value = rngFound.Offset(0, 1).Value

                        'Turn events back on
                        Application.EnableEvents = True
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End If


    'Cleanup
    Set tbl = Nothing
    Set rngFound = Nothing
    Set rngAutocorrect = Nothing
    Set cell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: For my overall goal, I would be willing to implement complex VBA scripts (even a hidden sheet or two), as long as the finished product requires minimal user interaction.

Comment: I added my VBA solution. See what you think and if it works for you. In my tests, it's an instant operation.

Comment: I will test this out sometime within the next few hours and see how it works.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work, but it could be because of my inexperience with VBA.

I created the new sheet, added some test terms, and implemented the code. The error I'm getting is a run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. The script it's pulling up as bad is:
**Set tbl = Sheet3.ListObjects("tblWordTable")**

I don't know if there's a special way to name the table or not.

Comment: There is, in fact, a special way to name the table. When you create a table (Insert ribbon > Table) it gives it a default name like `Table1` but you can change that. For 2010: On the Formulas ribbon, click on "Name Manager" around the middle of the screen. Select the default table name, click "Edit" at the top, change the name, and click OK.

Comment: Absolutely criminal that this answer got 0 votes and wasn't selected as correct. Ungrateful OP